# Reassignment to val issue

Tags: scala

```scala
def merge(
  left: mutable.ListBuffer[CaseClass],
  right: ListBuffer[CaseClass]
): ListBuffer[CaseClass] = {
  leftData.dimList = 
    newDimVal.patch(index,Seq(rightData.dimList(index)),0)
```

here i am getting Reassignment to val issue
where leftData.dimList and newDimVal both are ListBuffer

Answer (score 2):

`val`s in Scala are for immutable references. If you want to be able to reassign, you have to declare `dimList` as a `var`.

```
val a = 4
var b = 2
b = 7 // works
a = 3 // doesn't compile, citing a reassignment to val
```

Note that if `leftData` is a `case class`, its members are implicitly `val`s if you don't specify it differently. However, `case class`es should be used exclusively for immutable data.

Answer (score 1):

The lang already has simple ways to merge mutable\immutable collections.

#### Case Classes are Good for Modeling Immutable Data

You can’t reassign `leftData.dimList` because it is a val (i.e. immutable). It is possible to use vars in case classes but this is **discouraged**.

See the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html).

#### Iterable Collections can be Zipped

The whole suite of `zip` and `unzip` methods are useful to merge or un-merge collections.

```scala
val xs = ListBuffer(1,2,3)
val ys = ListBuffer(3,4,5)

xs
  .zip(ys)
  .map { case (fromA, fromB) => /*merge logic*/ }
```

Note: Here you could swap `ListBuffer` for `immutable.List`. Zip creates a new instance.